# Need to run a aws lambda function which takes more than 15 minutes to complete?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My Lambda function has limit 15 minutes which was 5 minutes ealier.Lambda process is automatically terminated after 15 minutes but my process takes more than 15 minutes. How I can manage ?

Comment: You might consider using Amazon EC2 for your processing, then auto-terminating the instance when the task is complete. See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Answer (score 29):

There is no way around this. If you're doing some sort of long running processing then your other option may be to run this task on an EC2 instance. If this long running process can be broken down in to multiple steps then you could look in to Lambda Step Functions.

15 Minutes is the max and this max can not be extended.

EDIT:

Recently I started running some long running tasks that are variable in length (anywhere from a couple minutes to several hours). To accomplish this I've been using AWS Fargate and my task is node.js script that is stored as a Docker container in ECR. Doing this was fairly easy and also is fairly cheap (I think we spent a little over $1 for running this task daily in a month). This may be something worth looking in to for others who may come across this answer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/scheduled_tasks.html

Comment: Is there any rationale given as to why 15 minutes is the maximum? It feels completely arbitrary.

Comment: Agreed. I'm guessing they could extend it if they wanted to. I'm wondering if they would lose money somewhere else (EC2) if they did. I would bet so.

Comment: @JohnAllen beyond the free tier, spawning a Task through ECS / Fargate is similarly priced for the same hardware as doing it in a Lambda so I'm not sure about this. It's still a pain though as the architecture of Fargate through all the Task definition + Docker + etc. is significantly more complex than a Lambda

Answer (score 25):

Typically use a Fat Lambda strategy or Step Function

**Fat Lambda Strategy**

> A Fat Lambda strategy is used when your *task is singular* but has a
> long-running execution time and/or you have heavy hardware
> requirements. The idea is that you would create a script that executes your long
> process and put it into a docker container that's hosted in Fargate.
> Meaning no limits to execution time and access to powerful hardware (How to create a Fat Lambda https://youtu.be/XUp9SHIHU8w)

**Step Function strategy**

> A Step Function strategy is used to break down your *entire process*
> into smaller steps. Usually, a step function strategy would work for
> you if your process could have lots of miniature stages linked
> together instead of a big colossal job attempting to do everything
> simultaneously. Bear in mind that a "Fat Lambda" can also be triggered
> by a Step Function (How to create a Step Function
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0XFX3WHg0w)

Also, another note, remember lambdas can also trigger other lambdas. So you might even be able to have different lambdas run bits of your lambda code. For example, a FOR loop sends off a lot of mini lambdas to run small tasks. You might not even need a Step Function or a Fat Lambda.

If you're stuck on what to choose, follow the below. It will help you reason with your problem.

Singular Lambda >> Lambda invoke another Lambda? >> Step Functions? >> Fargate (Fat Lambda)?

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks can you review again please, wasn't aware.

Answer (score 9):

If you can checkpoint the task then you can check the `getRemainingTimeInMillis` ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html)) and if the time is running out then invoke the same lambda with a parameter where to continue.

Something like this flow:

- start working (0% done)
- time is running low (40% done) => start a new lambda telling it to start from 40%
- old lambda is terminated, new lambda starts working (40%)
- when its time is running low, start a new lambda again (80%)
- the third lambda finishes the job

But it requires a very specific type of task to support this. If your require a single execution from start to finish then lambda is not a good choice for this.

Comment: You also need to be aware that you cannot expect any state to make it to the next invocation. Any state that you need would need to be passed into the next invocation or stored somewhere like S3.

Answer (score 4):

What do you think about using a lambda to trigger an ECS task? An ECS task just runs a containerized application for as long as it needs to run.

This blog post is relevant: https://www.gravitywell.co.uk/insights/using-ecs-tasks-on-aws-fargate-to-replace-lambda-functions/.

Comment: Could you please copy the relevant information of the linked blog post into your answer?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the Step function answer - here's a very simple playbook:

1. Work for 10 minutes
2. Write progress to S3
3. kick off another lambda to consume your progress
4. terminate

Once you're done, output.  Viola, infinite runtime lambda with very little effective overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Aws lambda is meant to be used for quick processing. if your task is this long then better choose some other way to develop that functionality. Although you can define the timeout property for AWS lambda, but that can not exceed 15 minutes.

As per you use case better to use EC2 for deploying you application and then terminate the EC2 instance when the processing is done or it remains idle more than the threshold time.

Refer the AW Lambda documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/index.html

Comment: I dont get why people always say a lambda should finish very quickly, at the end of the day its just a container running some code and AWS have extended the runtime to 15 minutes and the memory allocation to 10GB, and I fully expect them to increase the time allocation at some point soon.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot run a lambda for more than 15 mins!
But Yes you can manage this using Signals.

Basically, this will inform you to start plan B when plan A is not enough within 15 mins. If you can decouple the tasks in your process and add checkpoints in your process then the next lambda invocation can be picked up in plan B or you can somehow create entries in db in the plan B for the unprocessed parts. And reprocess them as a part of another run.

Framework here -
https://gist.github.com/kuharan/c2bfddac7bd8dc5702f6eec31729fb48

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else having the same issue, as others have stated, it is not possible.
However, it is possible to create long-running functions on top of AWS Lambda using [Durable](https://durablecloud.net/). Durabe invokes your lambda function and preserves it's state. This way your function can be restored and continue running even after the 15min limit.

For example, let's say we want to run indefinitely and check a background job's status and send a report when the job is complete.. We can create a Durable workflow:

```
@workflow.defn
class JobReportWorkflow:
    @workflow.run
    async def run(self, job_id: str) -> str:
        while True:
            print("Checking job status")
            job_status = await workflow.execute_activity(
                check_status,
                job_id
            )

            if job_status.finished:
                await workflow.execute_activity(
                    send_report,
                    job_status
                )
                return
        
            await asyncio.sleep(30 * 60) # Check back in 30min
```

Note that our workflow has to be deterministic (No use of random, network access, clock time and so on). This is because during function sleep, the lambda function stops. When the 30min sleep is complete, Durable invokes our function again and replays all the events to restore the function to it's previous state. Non-deterministic logic like our API call should be placed in an activity. This way Durable caches the result and can replay the workflow reliably.

```
@activity.defn
async def check_status(job_id: str) -> Status:
    # API call..

@activity.defn
async def send_report(job_status: Status):
    # Send report..
```

Durable is built on top of Temporal which is a durable execution engine.

Disclosure: I am the founder of Durable.