# Invoke lambda function asynchronously with proxy interface @LambdaFunction and async client

Tags: aws-lambda

I'd like to invoke our remote lambda micro-services from our java application remotely. I have issue that lambda might timeout for longer processing, in this case, I would like to call lambda asynchronously so that I can configure the call with a custom timeout longer than lambda's 15 minutes limit.

Here is my code,

```
            AWSLambda awsLambda;
            switch (invocationType) {
                case Event:
                    awsLambda = AWSLambdaAsyncClientBuilder.defaultClient();
                    break;
                case RequestResponse:
                default:
                    awsLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient();
                    break;
            }

            service = LambdaInvokerFactory.builder()
                    .lambdaClient(awsLambda)
                    .build(ILambdaProxyService.class);
```

Here is my ILambdaProxyService.java,

```
public interface ILambdaProxyService {

    @LambdaFunction(invocationType = InvocationType.RequestResponse)
    ServerResponse invoke(ServerRequest request);

    @LambdaFunction(invocationType = InvocationType.Event)
    ServerResponse invokeAsync(ServerRequest request);
}
```

**How would I make an asynchronous call using 'invokeAsync'?** Such that I can get hold of the callback handler or the Future object, and simply wait till the long-running lambda is done or my custom timeout exhausts.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure to understand what you mean here:

> so that I can configure the call with a custom timeout longer than
> lambda's 15 minutes limit

If your goal is to get your Lambda run more than 15 minutes (and eventually get your result, synchronously or asynchronously) then you can't, AWS Lambda has a hard limit of 15 minutes for runs (whatever the client is configured). For long-running processes you can use other solutions (StepFunctions, EC2, Fargate, ...) (you can find some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960787/need-to-run-a-aws-lambda-function-which-takes-more-than-15-minutes-to-complete)).

Comment: True, I was thinking another lambda service that relays the call to a legacy backend java app. In fact, this lambda does all the processing, so if runs longer than 15', there is no way to get around this. So ECS or Fargate is the more suitable solution for my case of this lambda service. Thanks.

Comment: Can the Java client connection wait the entire ~15 minutes? So still, how to make the asynchronous call, so that I can push the result in a queue or just loop till the result is back.